# Animating background stops after opened and closed Facebook's login view

Tags: ios, animation, swift2, facebook-login

In my login view there are a continuous background animating and a Facebook button for login.

The problem is that when I open Facebook login page (Safari) and close it, the animation stops as it can be seen bellow:

[image]

Following my animation code:

```
    //MARK: - View animations
    func animateLogin(){

        self.animateBackground(imageName: "backgroundLogin-layer1", scrolling: .Left, timing: 30.0)
        self.animateBackground(imageName: "backgroundLogin-layer2", scrolling: .Right, timing: 35.0)
        self.animateBackground(imageName: "backgroundLogin-layer3", scrolling: .Right, timing: 50.0)
        self.animateBackground(imageName: "backgroundLogin-layer4", scrolling: .Right, timing: 60.0)

    }

    func animateBackground(imageName img: String, scrolling side: Side, timing duration: NSTimeInterval){

        let backgroundImage = UIImage(named:img)!
        let amountToKeepImageSquare = backgroundImage.size.height - self.view.frame.size.height

        let backgroundImageView1 = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)
        backgroundImageView1.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin.x, y: self.view.frame.origin.y, width: backgroundImage.size.width - amountToKeepImageSquare, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        self.view.addSubview(backgroundImageView1)

        var positionXSecondImage: CGFloat
        var multiplier: CGFloat

        if side == .Right{
            //Scrolling right
            positionXSecondImage = (backgroundImageView1.frame.size.width * -1.0)
            multiplier = 1
        }else{
            //Scrolling left
            positionXSecondImage = backgroundImageView1.frame.size.width
            multiplier = -1
        }

        let backgroundImageView2 = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)
        backgroundImageView2.frame = CGRect(x: positionXSecondImage, y: self.view.frame.origin.y, width: backgroundImage.size.width - amountToKeepImageSquare, height: self.view.frame.height)
        self.view.addSubview(backgroundImageView2)

        self.view.sendSubviewToBack(backgroundImageView1)
        self.view.sendSubviewToBack(backgroundImageView2)

        // Animate background
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, options: [.Repeat, .CurveLinear], animations: {
            backgroundImageView1.frame = CGRectOffset(backgroundImageView1.frame, multiplier * backgroundImageView1.frame.size.width, 0.0)
            backgroundImageView2.frame = CGRectOffset(backgroundImageView2.frame, multiplier * backgroundImageView2.frame.size.width, 0.0)
            }, completion: nil)

    }
```

I'm calling **animateLogin** function in *ViewDidLoad* method and I have already tried calling it in *ViewDidAppear*

```
    //MARK: - App's lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ...
        ...
        //Calling function taht makes background animted
        self.animateLogin()
        ...
        ...


    }
```

I need to restart animating after close Facebook login view.

Comment: @VijayPalwe, in this case applicationDidBecomeActive is not called after closing Facebook View.

Comment: I've already tried calling it in viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear and didn't work

Comment: Facebook provides delegate methods for successes, errors, and canceling. Have you tried implementing those delegate functions and restarting the animation in there?